# CASE WHEN SQL - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to get data from table and based on one column add new column named 'Expensive'
Although after looking online my syntax does not get accepted.

Code:

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_price
CASE 
WHEN product_price > 10000 THEN 'Expensive'
WHEN product_price < 100 THEN 'Cheap'
ELSE 'Medium' 
END AS cost 
FROM products;
```

Error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
WHEN product_price > 10000 THEN 'Expensive'
WHEN product_price <' at line 2

Comment: missing coma after `product_description, product_price`

Answer (score 2):

You missed comma(,) before case

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_price,
( CASE 
  WHEN product_price > 10000 THEN 'Expensive'
  WHEN product_price < 100 THEN 'Cheap'
  ELSE 'Medium' 
  END
) AS cost 
FROM products;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_name, product_description, product_price,
```

Been missing a comma.